# postfix just installed on ubuntu, but mail() not working in php

Tags: php, email, postfix

I have a new server. Just installed Postfix (apt-get install mailutils), and configured postfix as "Internet site". Works fine when I'm logged in as regular user on the command prompt and use "mail xx@domain.com" to send a mail. When I try sending mail via PHP, nothing happens. I tried mail("xx@domain.com", "subject", "my test");, but nothing is sent. When I look at /var/log/mail.log, nothing appears (though everything appears when sending from command line, without PHP).

When I didn't change my php.ini line

```
;sendmail_path =
```

, nothing appears in the mail.log file.
When, to test, I added

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t
```

I get an error in my /var/log/mail.log, saying

```
fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option
```

(which seemed to be specified, according to me...?)

Any idea what could be causing this? How can I get my PHP to send mail?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by re-installing (a new version of) PHP. Since no postfix was installed when compiling the first time, the mail() was disabled...